# How to tell Watson conversation to not recognize strings as numbers

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm facing a strange issue with IBM Watson Conversation when capturing numbers in Spanish language:

In Spanish when you write (or say), "please give me an answer" (*por favor, dame una respuesta*) or "I want to talk with a professional" (*quiero hablar con un profesional*), Watson recognize the words "*una*" and "*un*" as a number. Yes, it is a number (the number 1) but in these phrases they do not have the meaning of a number, they work as an article.

Do you know how to tell Watson to not recognize strings as numbers? I have been thinking about patterns but the numbers can have different length.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Official documentation, the `@sys-number` system entity detects numbers that are written using either numerals or words. In **either** case, a *numeric value* is returned.

When you enable the System Entity @sys-number, this entity *always tries to detect* if the user typed some number, there are the recognized formats:

- 21
- twenty one (in your case, works with un, una, etc)
- 3.13

You can see this table showing how to use this entity with other examples:

[image]

So, Watson will recognize these values (un, una) like one number, and currently don't have exceptions or configuration for does not recognize something, like your example, the word typed by the user.
If you want for some purpose to send to the user the 'una' or 'un'(literal format example), just add in your conversation response:

```
The number is @sys-number.literal
```

And the return in the bot will be:

```
The number is un?
```

- See more about [@sys-number](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-number) System entity.
- See more about [System entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html).

Comment: Sayuri, thank you for your answer. You have done a very good explanation about how @sys-number works in Watson Conversation but it doesn't help me. The numeric value always is detected and it breaks the slot in the dialog because Watson fill the value. The only method I've found to avoid that is add a logic in the external application which is the intermediate between user and Watson to get the entity value and look for strings or number.

Comment: `string input = conversation.Input.text;

int start = Int32.Parse(item.Location[0].ToString());

int end = Int32.Parse(item.Location[1].ToString());

int length = end - start;

string word = input.Substring(start, length);

if(Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^\d+$"))  values.Add(item.Value);`

Comment: I understand. This is the purpose for this system entity. My answer is for Watson Conversation, with code, for a while in your purpose will work. But, when you to need to identify after, maybe you'll have problems